# updating and synchronous running of paragraph via REST api does not updating ui and paragraph results

Tags: apache-zeppelin

In order to give user interactive graph designing interface. I am using zepplin rest apis and zepplin iframe. Problem is after updating and running paragraph, UI is not changing. Same problem is posted as issue [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZEPPELIN-2296).